# Appcompat and Recyclerview versions difference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

I just create a project from Android Studio and gradle file are like below,

The thing is, appcompat and recyclerview should be same version I guess, I tried lots of things but I couldn't able to find same versions.

How can I solve this problem?

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [androidx release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) (instead of support libraries release).
You can use:

```
androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta03
```

or

```
androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele! So it will not be a problem different versions with appcombat?

Comment: No, at least not currently.